# How to know which file is selected in open dialog in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to open a file dialog. In that I have to choose one file either an XML or MAP file. If the choosen file is MAP file then I have to do step-A or if the choosen file is XML then I have to do step-B. My question is how to know which file is selected from the dialog box application?

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml|MAP Files|*.map";
fileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

How to know which file is selected from the above filter ?

[image: open file dialog]

Comment: This dialogbox is modal, how can your code catch the selected index change on that combo? You should wait the OK click and then process the filename requested. Or I'm misunderstanding your intentions?

Comment: @Steve: You can hook the dialog and receive notifications of these events. Basically, you attach an event handler method, and that method will be called each time the user does a particular thing in the dialog. But it doesn't sound like to me that's what Amarnath is wanting here.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks, you are right of course, but ... how can I say? Shooting a fly with a gun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
   string fileName = OpenFileDialog.Filename;

    if(fileName.EndsWith(".xml"))
    {
    //
    }
    else if(fileName.EndsWith(".map"))
    {
     //
    }
```

Comment: Why would you do this when you could use the [`FileDialog.FilterIndex` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filterindex.aspx) to determine which filter was selected when the user clicked OK in the dialog?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that property, had I known about it in advance I would have suggested it instead of my answer. Thanks for the link though, learn something new everyday here :)

Comment: I have done using Dialog.FileName.Endswith(""). Thanks for suggesting Endswith() function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that while it is open.

When user presses OK then pass `OpenFileDialog.Filename` in `Path.GetExtension` method or `OpenFileDialog.Filename.Endswith(".xml")`.

Check if extension is XML then do `x` step otherwise `y` step.

**EDIT**

See for functionality that you require, there has to be an event in open file dialog.

There are 2 `OpenFileDialog` Class

1. `System.Windows.Forms`
2. `Microsoft.Win32`

Both have only one event `OpenFileDialog.FileOK` which you can look for.

Comment: Yep I have already done that its working fine. But just curious to know "is there some way such that I could know which file is selected from the filter instead of getting the file and getting the extension?"

Comment: Your user could even select a file which doesn't end with xml or map. Just type `*.*` in the File name textbox (press Enter) and pick a different one. The filter is there to help your users select a valid type, but it does not enforce it. This means you will have to check the return value anyway.

Comment: @Davio Thanks for the suggestion. You made me rethink again about my design.

Answer (score 0):

```
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                //do something here
            }
        }
```

The *FileName* attribute of *OpenFileDialog* is the file name selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could even use similar extensions in a switch with stacked labels and use the default case for unsupported file types:

```
switch (extension)
{
    case "xml":
    case "xaml":
        Debug.WriteLine("It's an XML!");
        break;
    case "map":
        Debug.WriteLine("It's a map!");
        break;
    default:
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an XML or MAP file");
        // Show the dialog again
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the above answers will work if luckily all the filters have different extensions. but if we are talking about different File versions with the same extension then we can get the selected filter through this code:

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Excel 97|*.xls|Excel 95|*.xls";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Filer index is 1 based.
            switch (dlg.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    //Filter name: Excel 97
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Filter name: Excel 95
                    break;
            }
        }
```